Do I need USB to program the stm32 via SWD?
I designed a PCB that has a STM32F405RGT6 as its MCU. I took out the USB in the design because I thought that I only need it for the power. Now I am wondering if I can program it via SWD with only the ST-Link/V2 and a LiPo battery as the power input. Any insights are very helpful!



No, you don't need USB.
Yes, as long as you power the board and MCU gets 3.3V supply, you can program with SWD or JTAG. Using ST-Link. That's what they are for. Except for ST-Link clones, they are a waste of time and money.

Thank you very much! I already have the PCB, right now I am waiting for the battery to arrive and I thought that I already screwed up.
